# Accessing NS_OPTIONS in swift option unavailable

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, enums, bitmask

I defined an NS_OPTIONS in Objective-C .h file:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS (NSInteger, Options){
    OptionsOne,
    OptionsTwo,
    OptionsThree
};
```

Now when accessing from Swift:

```
public func myFunc() -> Options {
    return [.one, .two]
}
```

I am getting this error:

> 'one' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set.

But I am not getting this error for .two or .three. It appears only for the first option.

Comment: The relevant part of the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" guide is in the [Options Set section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID169) – "*When importing C enumeration marked with the `NS_OPTIONS` macro, Swift marks any members that have a value of 0 as unavailable, because Swift uses an empty option set to specify no options.*" Although in your case, you never really intended for `OptionsOne` to have a value of 0.

Answer (score 4):

By default, in Swift 3, an `NS_OPTIONS` enumerand equating to `0` is not imported into Swift by name. You have to use `[]` in Swift to get it.

When you changed the enumerand's value to `1`, the name was imported.

If you think about it, this makes perfect sense. `NS_OPTIONS` is for bitmasks. Thus, if (let's say) `.one` is `0` and `.two` is `1`, there is no useful meaning to the expression `[.one, .two]` because there is no information added by the presence of the `.one`.

What you were doing, on the other hand, was *always* a misuse of `NS_OPTIONS`, since it was not a bitmask. Your modification turned it into one. (Objective-C does not magically generate bitmask-appropriate values for you.)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this to be adding explicit bitmask value to the options:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS (NSInteger, Options){
    OptionsOne = 1 << 0,
    OptionsTwo = 1 << 1,
    OptionsThree = = 1 << 2
};
```

and the error went away.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact that the bitmask value is explicit. It's because you _changed_ the value from `0` to `1`.